# How to encrypt the Key and IV which used in AES Encryption Model in android App

Tags: android, .net, encryption, aes

I have android application which has payment gateway and another services.Iam using AES Model to encrypt and decrypt data between the app and the server.Iam using KEY and IV constants which stored in android class. My problem is how to encrypt these constants ( IV and Key) in the android application to prevent any attacker to make decompile for the APK file and show these constants.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Encrypt the Key with a RSA Public Key and only the Server knows the privatekey for this public key and can decrypt it.

You decrypt the AES Key with the private key on the serverside and use the decrypted AES Key to decrypt your original message.

//Edit

This is an example for the Java Code in Android Studio. My RSA Public key is stored in the shared preferences.

When the app is installed it makes a call to a Server, where a RSA Key pair is produced, both keys are saved in a Database and the Public Key is sent to the Device and saved in the shared preferences. Whenever something Needs to be Encrypted the stored Public Key is created and used for Encryption and only the Server knows the private key.

```
byte[] ENCRYPTED_AES_KEY_IN_BYTE = null;
String ENCRYPTED_AES_KEY;
cipher = null;
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPwithSHA-1andMGF1Padding");

// Get the shared preferences where the public key is stored
// SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(preferences,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// get the Publickey stored as string in the shared preferences
String stringkey = preferences.getString(PUBLICKEY,"");

// create a public RSA Key from the stored key
X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.decode(stringkey,Base64.DEFAULT));
KeyFactory keyFactory;
PublicKey key =null;
keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
key = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);

//Encrypt the AES key with the RSA public key
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
ENCRYPTED_AES_KEY_IN_BYTES = AES_KEY.getEncoded();

ENCRYPTED_AES_KEY_IN_BYTE = cipher.doFinal(ENCRYPTED_AES_KEY_IN_BYTE);
ENCRYPTED_AES_KEY = Base64.encodeToString(ENCRYPTED_AES_KEY_IN_BYTE,Base64.DEFAULT);

//ENCRYPTED_AES_KEY is now the Encrypted AES Key as string
```

// EDIT #2

Create a RSA KEY pair at the server

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS8);
$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8);
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
extract($rsa->createKey());
$publickey = str_replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n","",$publickey);
$publickey = str_replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----","",$publickey);
$privatekey = str_replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n","",$privatekey);
$privatekey = str_replace( "-----END PRIVATE KEY-----","",$privatekey);
```

the privatekey is saved to a Database and the Publickey is sent to the Client to Encrypt data.

To Decrypt the Data on the Serverside again

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PUBLIC_FORMAT_PKCS8);
$rsa->setPrivateKeyFormat(CRYPT_RSA_PRIVATE_FORMAT_PKCS8);
$rsa->setEncryptionMode( CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
$IV     = base64_decode($IV);
$AESkey    = base64_decode($AESkey);
$rsa->loadKey($privatekey);
$AESkey    = $rsa->decrypt($AESkey);

// replace empty spaces with a + , this is something which can happen when you use a http request

$encrypteddata = str_replace(" ", "+", $encrypteddata);
$encrypteddata   = base64_decode($encrypteddata);
$method = "AES-256-CBC";
$decrypteddata   = openssl_decrypt($encrypteddata, $method, $AESkey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$IV);
```

In this Code is not included how you store the privatekey in a Database and how you get it back from the Database.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but do you have any sample code in java as mobile side and .net as server side which use above method that you mentioned

Comment: Edited a method to Encrypt an AES Key which can be sent as a String to the Server, but i don't have a .net solution, only a php script.

Comment: No problem could you please add sample code uaing java awith php. The idea is to protect and hide key and IV from attackers because when you decompile any android app you can get the source code which easy to fetch the IV amd KEY then anyone can decrypt the data which comming from the server.

Comment: Your Approach seems not very safe, you should never store a static AES KEY at Client side. Especially for payments this is a very bad idea. For such a method, where you ENCRYPT on one side and DECRYPT on the other side RSA is made.

Comment: added a php Code to generate a RSA Keypair and use it to Decrypt a AES key and use the decrypted AES key to decrypt the original Data